# calculating frequency with apple's auriotouch example

Tags: iphone, audio, signal-processing, fft

I am working on a program that needs to capture the frequency of sound from a guitar.  I have modified the aurioTouch example to output the frequency by using the frequency with the highest magnitude.  It works ok for high notes but is very inaccurate on the lower strings.  I believe it is due to overtones.  I researched ways on how to solve this problem such as Cepstrum Analysis but I am lost on how to implement this within the example code as it is unclear and hard to follow without comments.  any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Since the aurioTouch example already has the capability to capture audio, do an FFT and display a spectrum, it can't be too hard to find the part that does the FFT etc and modify it to do what you want at that point, surely ?

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4501089/fft-pitch-detection-for-guitar-string

Answer (score 4):

As you have discovered, musical pitch is not the same as peak frequency.

But trying to investigate algorithms while trying to work with real-time audio is not easy.

I suggest you separate the problems.  Record some music sounds (guitar plucks, etc.) on your Mac into raw sound files.  Try your chosen pitch estimation algorithms on these recorded sample sets.  Then, after you get this working, figure out how to integrate your code into the iOS audio and Accelerate (for FFT) frameworks.